# How to pass parameter in HQL query

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

find below my HQL query

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("select u from UserLog u where u.userLogSerialno = " + "(select max(uu.userLogSerialno) from UserLog uu where uu.userId = u.userId)");
```

This query is working fine but in this, I want to pass the value of userId but I am not able to figure out how to do this. 
Kindly Help..!!
Thanks in Advance..!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I is very simple to add parameter to an HQL

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select u from UserLog u where u.userLogSerialno = " + "(select max(uu.userLogSerialno) from UserLog uu where uu.userId = :userId)").setParameter("userId", 15);
```

here i have hard coded 15 you can simply use variable instead of it

Answer (score 12):

Simple example:

```
Integer id = 1;
Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee e where e.idEmployee=:id");
query.setParameter("id", id);
```

Answer (score 4):

**NAMEDPARAMETER**

```
String hql = "from com.baba.app.Model.Employee where mngId=:id or mngName=:name";
            Query q = ses.createQuery(hql);
            q.setParameter("id", 121);
            q.setParameter("name", "baba");
```

**PARAMETER**

```
String hql = "from com.baba.app.Model.Employee where mngId= ? or mngName= ?";
            Query q = ses.createQuery(hql);
            q.setParameter(0, 121);
            q.setParameter(1, "baba");
```